# ¿Cómo utilizar loop for o while para realizar un programa que encripte y desencripte texto?

Tags: javascript, funciones, bucle-for, bucles

Inicié un curso de principiante en JS y tengo que realizar un proyecto que encripte y desencripte un texto recibido como parámetro. Entiendo que hay formas más resumidas y eficientes para realizar esta tarea pero quisiera utilizar bucles for o while en caso de ser posible. Necesito un poco de guía porque me encuentro estancado.
La consigna que recibí es la siguiente...

Las "llaves" de encriptación que utilizaremos son:

`La letra "e" es convertida para "enter"`
`La letra "i" es convertida para "imes"`
`La letra "a" es convertida para "ai"`
`La letra "o" es convertida para "ober"`
`La letra "u" es convertida para "ufat"`

Lo que realicé (de antemano sé que está mal e incompleto) fue:

```html
function cambiarVocal(texto){
var vocales = ['a','e','i','o','u'];
var nuevaLetra = [];

for(var i = 0; i < vocales.length; i++){

     if(i == vocales[0]){
          nuevaLetra.push('ai');
     }
     if(i == vocales[1]){
          nuevaLetra.push('enter');
     }
     if(i == vocales[2]){
          nuevaLetra.push('imes');
     }
     if(i == vocales[3]){
          nuevaLetra.push('ober');
     }
     if(i == vocales[4]){
          nuevaLetra.push('ufat');
     }

}

}
```

Sé que la función no está trabajando con el parámetro texto. Pensé en tomar al parámetro como un array (no se como podría hacerlo) y compararlo con la variable vocales (en caso que las letras coincidan realizar la encriptación). Y para desencriptar tampoco se como realizarlo. Como dije antes apenas soy principiante en programación. No espero me resuelvan el programa sino sólo me den algunas indicaciones. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: La lógica es buena, pero está mal aplicada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay un par de errores aquí.

1. Nunca estas usando la variable `texto` que te llega como parámetro, supongo que es la que debes transformar y no pasa por tu algoritmo de transformación.
2. Estas ciclando con base en `vocales` debería ser por la cantidad de letras que tenga `texto`
3. Tu `if` jamás será eficiente, estas comparando dos cosas distintas, por ejemplo, el primer ciclo del `for` el `if` a ojos humanos se vería así

   ```
   if( 0 == 'a')
   if( 0 == 'e')
   if( 0 == 'i')
   if( 0 == 'o')
   if( 0 == 'u')
   ```

Eso no tiene sentido

Te voy a compartir un script de cómo yo lo haría y te lo documento, te dejaré links a las funciones que puedan ser nuevas para ti, así verás como funciona.
Quizá valga la pena quitar los comentarios del script para que se vea mucho más limpio.

```js
function cambiarVocal(texto) {
  // convertimos el texto en un arreglo de sus mismas letras
  const letras = texto.split(''); // ['H','o','l','a', ' ', 'm','u','n','d','o']
  
  // Hacemos un mapa de llaves, cada vocal será convertida en algo distinto
  const llaves = {
    a: 'ai',
    e: 'enter',
    i: 'imes',
    o: 'ober',
    u: 'ufat'
  };
  
  // La función debe regresar el resultado cifrado
  return cifrado = 
  // Vamos a transformar cada uno de los valores del arreglo en algo distinto con la función map()
  letras
  // Preguntamos si en las llaves existe la letra que esté actualmente convirtiendose, si existe se convierte, si no, se regresa tal y como está
  .map( letra => llaves[letra] ? llaves[letra] : letra)
  // el map() te regresa un arreglo, hay que convertirlo a cadena con join('')
  .join('');
}

console.log(cambiarVocal('Hola mundo'));
```

Función [split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

Función [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Función [join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

[Operador ternario](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Comment: Gracias amigo, sabía que el código que hice tenía muchos errores. Explicas muy bien, necesitaría ver más teoría para entender algunas cosas sobre el código que me pasaste. Gracias por los enlaces de las funciones.